# Nodejs / replace AnyFile Package

Tags: node.js

For security reason in my workplace I need to stop using "Any-File" (Please don't ask me where I work)

It is used in one part of the code

```
let af = new AnyFile();
..
af.from(file_to_move).to(dest_folder, function(err) {
```

I wonder if I may replace these lines with a simple javascript function

```
var object = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var file = object.GetFile(file1);
file.Move(dir);
```

Please shoot me if this is really stupid question, as I start getting used to it with "js expert"... (I have to say python guys are more cool)

EDIT_________
ActiveXObject is part of the Windows Script host, and not available in Linux. Not sure I need it.

Comment: Your use case is for local files only?

Comment: I have to check that tomorrow morning,. I guess it is

Comment: No one cares where you work :}, But for node.js, I suggest you check the [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) API.